# Core Location In Conjunction with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, restkit, core-location, grand-central-dispatch

I am using RestKit in my app for all web/network calls. On launch, in the AppDelegate, I start updating the user's location. By the time the user approves the app to use the location (on first launch), the app would have moved to the `RootViewController` and started the RestKit HTTP call. The HTTP call requires the user's location, and therefore, will fail.

What are some ways around that? How can I work with Core Location while utilizing RestKit's concurrency?

I am aware that the way the app is structured (update UI upon web service retrieval) is very dangerous. I am trying to avoid as much refactors as I can (management orders). What are ways around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not ask for location on AppDelegate.

Instead navigate to RootController and in ViewDidLoad, call startUpdatingLocation & immediately pop up a view with processing image like UIActivityIndicator.

Upon getting the location successfully, a protocol method is fired, remove the pop up view here and send the RestKit Call with acquired coordinates.

Comment: When a view appears with an activity indicator, is the `RootViewController` going to stop there until the view is popped off the stack?

Comment: nope.. root controller won't stop. but the view with activity indicator should hide it. Do not send the rest call until the location is determined.